# Size of messages exchanged between workers

Tags: dask-distributed

When using Dask Distributed on multiple computers, the data is being exchanged between workers, client, and scheduler. This data is chunked into messages of 64 MB (it appears). Can this value be changed? If so, what is the relevant configuration option for that? If there is not option, can anyone point to the relevant source-code where this can be changed. I am asking this question for a NumPy application.

Answer (score 1):

The following flag in distributed/protocol/utils.py sets this value:

BIG_BYTES_SHARD_SIZE = 2 ** 26